# ion-card is not a known element

Tags: angular, ionic3

I am new to angular and Ionic. I am using
"@angular/forms": "^4.3.1"
"ionic-angular": "^3.5.3"
I have installed the ionic-angular and @angular/forms package. I am getting the following error message.

```
Unhandled Promise rejection: Template parse errors:
'ion-card-header' is not a known element:
1. If 'ion-card-header' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'ion-card-header' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message. ("

      <ion-card>
        [ERROR ->]<ion-card-header>
          Header
        </ion-card-header>
```

any thought how to fix will be really appreciated.

[image: Code that I have with me. both ts and html files]

I have placed the  into the  and its also started complaining about . Please see the image below.

[image: screen shot of the errors received]

### when I run "ionic info". I get the following message in the terminal.

```
$ ionic info
[WARN] You are not in an Ionic project directory. Project context may be
       missing.

global packages:

    @ionic/cli-utils : 1.5.0
    Ionic CLI        : 3.5.0

System:

    Node       : v6.11.1
    OS         : Windows 10
    Xcode      : not installed
    ios-deploy : not installed
    ios-sim    : not installed
    npm        : 3.10.10
```

---

I am basically in the process of making a library where I will have all components needed and then I will use these component in a seperate project.

```
 "dependencies": {
    "@angular/forms": "^4.3.1",
    "ionic-angular": "^3.5.3",
    "ionicons": "^3.0.0"
  },
  "peerDependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^4.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.0.0",
    "@compodoc/compodoc": "^1.0.0-beta.9",
    "@types/jasmine": "^2.5.47",
    "@types/karma": "^0.13.35",
    "@types/node": "^7.0.18",
    "@types/webpack": "^2.2.15",
    "@types/webpack-env": "^1.13.0",
    "angular2-template-loader": "^0.6.2",
    "awesome-typescript-loader": "^3.1.3",
    "codecov": "^2.2.0",
    "codelyzer": "^3.0.1",
    "concurrently": "^3.4.0",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.1",
    "gh-pages": "^1.0.0",
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "gulp-inline-ng2-template": "^4.0.0",
    "istanbul-instrumenter-loader": "^2.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "^2.6.1",
    "json-loader": "^0.5.4",
    "karma": "^1.7.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.1.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.1.0",
    "karma-mocha-reporter": "^2.2.3",
    "karma-sourcemap-loader": "^0.3.7",
    "karma-webpack": "^2.0.3",
    "node-sass": "^4.5.2",
    "raw-loader": "^0.5.1",
    "rimraf": "2.6.1",
    "rxjs": "^5.3.1",
    "sass-loader": "^6.0.5",
    "source-map-explorer": "^1.3.3",
    "to-string-loader": "^1.1.5",
    "ts-node": "^3.0.4",
    "tslint": "^5.2.0",
    "typescript": "2.4.0",
    "webpack": "^2.5.1",
    "webpack-angular-externals": "^1.0.2",
    "webpack-rxjs-externals": "^1.0.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.10"
  }
```

I am new to ionic and angular.

Comment: Please show you main app.module.ts and app.component.ts.

Comment: [Please don't post your code as an image.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 2):

From your above code, you have missed to close your ion-card.

```
<ion-card>

  <ion-card-header>

  </ion-card-header>

</ion-card>
```

**Update 1:**

Number of issues I see in your code,

Selector should have the same name as your **.ts** file

```
@Component({
 selector: 'ionic-test.component',
 templateUrl: 'ionic-test.component.html'
})
```

Make sure your component tags are inside **ion-content**. For example,

```
<ion-content>

  <ion-grid>
   <ion-row> </ion-row>
   <ion-row> </ion-row>
  </ion-grid>

  <ion-card>
   <ion-card-header>

   </ion-card-header>
  </ion-card>

</ion-content>
```

Try moving your .scss to **ion-content** and change the .scss name to something different.

```
<ion-content class="ionic-test.component.styles">

</ion-content>
```

Also make sure the **.ts, .html, .scss** file are in the same root folder

**Update 2:**

Possible things which went wrong based on your recent edit,

1. You don't have the node_modules folder created which has all the libraries, go to your project root in Terminal and run the below command. It will install all the modules from your **package.json** file.

   `npm install`

**Note:** To see if node modules from package.json file are installed just run the below command by going to your project root in Terminal

```
 npm info
```

2. When creating the ionic project, you didn't follow the correct steps, follow the steps as per the [ionic documentation](https://ionicframework.com/docs/intro/installation/) and create a new project as outlined to see if it is working

Comment: None of the component is accessible for instance ion-grid is also not accessible. it is also giving the same error message that its not a known element.

<ion-grid>
  <ion-row>
    <ion-col col-12>This column will take 12 columns</ion-col>
  </ion-row>
  <ion-row>
    <ion-col col-6>This column will take 6 columns</ion-col>
  </ion-row>
</ion-grid>

I have following packages in package.json
"@angular/forms": "^4.3.1",
"ionic-angular": "^3.5.3",
"ionicons": "^3.0.0"  

I have a feeling that ionic are not working at all for me. I can see in the node_modules that grid is there. :(

Comment: Vikram Ezhil: now it has also started complaining about <ion-content> I have place another screenshot of the error message at the end of my question.

Comment: Did you install ionic in the first place? open Terminal and type "ionic info" without the quotes and let me know what info you see. Possibly you never installed ionic in your system.

Comment: Vikram Ezhil: I have add the result at the end of my question. I have also placed the packages from package.json

Comment: See my edit and please also make sure you have followed the steps in creating an ionic project as per the official doc.

Comment: Vikram Ezhil: but I have the node_modules folder already there. As I am also new on stackoverflow so its not allowing me to add more than 2 images otherwise I was willing to add tree structure that I have.

Comment: Vikram Ezhil: components are working now but theme is not getting applied

Answer (score 1):

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicApp, IonicModule } from 'ionic-angular';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { MyCustomModule } from '../../lib';


@NgModule({

imports: [
BrowserModule,
MyCustomModule,
IonicModule.forRoot(AppComponent)
],
declarations: [ AppComponent ],
bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

Thanks Vikram Ezhil for your time.

However theme supported by Ionic by default are still not working.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix this issue by disabling the angular ivy complier, in **tsconfig.app.json**

```
"angularCompilerOptions": {
    "enableIvy": false 
}, 
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the import of IonicModule in the Ts of your component and make sure to make the module a standalone module by adding

```
@Component({
standalone: true,
imports: [IonicModule] )}
```

This worked for me, in a ionic 6 app. Hope it helps you. (: